# What is the name of this bird?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

Does anyone know the name of the bird in the pictures? It was found in the south of Spain in the month of June. (it is certainly neither a house sparrow nor a swallow nor a robin). Thanks for the help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It could be female "Common blackbird" (Turdus merula)

Comment: Yes, it is may be a female, but it is surely not a "Common blackbird".

Comment: what is its size? otherwise tell compared with other known birds.

Comment: Sorry I don't have its exact size. It looks like a house sparrow, but it is a little smaller than a house sparrow. Its head is also smaller than the head of a house sparrow.

Comment: Is it possible that it was a species escaped from captivity?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. Maybe.

Comment: I asked if it would be escaped because by the colors it looks like a [Chestnut Sparrow](http://www.oiseaux.net/oiseaux/photos/moineau.d.emin.html) but it does not live in Europe but in Africa (Kenya, Tanzania and around). Otherwise it could be another sparrow family (the shape of the beak looks it is the Passeridae family) but difficult to say like this.

Comment: Couldn't it be a juvenile of some well known species ?

Comment: http://www.king5.com/story/news/local/pets-and-animals/2015/04/05/little-brown-bird-sings-happy-easter-song/25335167/

Comment: Yes it could also be a juvenile but I do not know too much about variation of colors for these birds; it could also be so old that it just get dry and loose its original colors.

Comment: The plumage looks in-between adult and juvenile. I think it's a fledgling, which is why no one can really identify it.

Answer (score -1):

Thats a difficult one but my gut feeling is a 'bunting' and maybe a Rock Bunting juv ? - the bill is definitely bunting-like and there does seem to be a black and white eye stripe going on . There arent that many buntings in the south of Spain especially with a very warm brown colouring